# Remove whitespace left by element removal using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using an XSLT empty template to remove a node from my XML. that is, `<xsl:template match="note"/>`. It works fine but I am left with an empty line between the nodes either side of it. I want to retain whitespace in general and have indented output but just get rid of this blank line. Is there a way to do that or would I have to run through teh document a second time and match somehow on the blank line?

```xml
...
<name>Keep whitespace</name>
                                       <-- where the <note/> element was
<favourite-color>keep white space</favourite-color>
...
```

Ideally I'd have:

```xml
...
<name>Keep whitespace</name>
<favourite-color>keep white space</favourite-color>
...
```

Comment: In many cases it can suffice to strip white space when parsing and to indent the output when serializing: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/><xsl:output indent="yes"/>`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @MartinHonnen. If you'd like to post as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases it can suffice to strip white space when parsing and to indent the output when serializing: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/><xsl:output indent="yes"/>`.

Or you can use `<xsl:template match="note | text()[not(normalize-space()) and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::note]]"/>`.